# I am trying to get General property page on selection of element in BIRT

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin, birt-emitter

I am trying to create BIRT emitter in eclipse and  I am facing problem in getting General property page on selection of element in BIRT. 
Please help me. Thanks

Comment: Can you explain the specific problem you're having? In its current form, it's highly unlikely that anyone here will be able to help answer your question.

Comment: I have created the property page (more than 5 property items)in the property editor but I want to display properties related to only item. for example: on click on the text only the related property should display on property page. and if I click on the label related properties should display.